"Royal Toilet", TV movie
I'm hoping someone can provide information on a movie I saw on TV some time ago. I haven't been able to conjure up anything via Google. As I recall:
The movie was a comedy called "Royal Toilet", which I believe I saw on PBS sometime in the early 1980s. It took place in a European country (Denmark stands out in my mind but I'm not certain that's correct), mostly at a factory. The plot concerned an upcoming royal visit to the factory.
The complication (and title) come from the fact that the king (prince?) was suffering from some sort of digestive problems and needed to have a toilet available on short notice. The factory's toilets were deemed unsuitable for royalty, so a special "royal" toilet had to be constructed just for the visit. This job fell to the a factory foreman who was an ardent anti-royalist. Since the toilet would only need to serve for a single use, it wasn't plumbed, but instead emptied into a bucket.
Eventually the royal visit comes and goes without need for the royal facility. The closing shot features the foreman who constructed it deciding that someone should use it, and entering. We hear him singing anti-royalist songs while he goes about his business.
Google finds no shortage of hits for me, all completely irrelevant. Can anyone point me to information about this movie?

Pretty sure it's this Swedish movie "Kunglig toilette" (literally "Royal Toilet") from 1986
https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunglig_toilette
Translated:
https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=sv&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fsv.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FKunglig_toilette&edit-text=
The film is set in a small municipality where King Carl XVI Gustaf will arrive at his Eriksgata. There is high pressure on the municipality of preparations for the royal visit with song, music, food, cultural elements and more. Everyone seems to still be satisfied with the king to come, except one - Egon Karlsson, deputy mayor and member of the Republican Association. Karlsson tries to get his wife and their party colleagues in the Social Democrats to avert the costly royal visit but poorly understood. Everyone in the community looks forward to the visit, not least the owner of the resort's large industry that see the chance to get the business associates from Japan to visit him to meet Queen Silvia.
During the last days before Eriksgatan arise, however, a crisis. They have forgotten that two special toilets for the king and queen must be available. The assignment to hastily get to two lyxtoaletter goes to erik gates opponent Egon Karlsson, who runs a small construction firm. When the big day has come, things go despite all the planning awry.
In the film's final scene is Egon Karlsson himself the only one who uses the specially built toilets, singing "The Internationale".
(I see google-translate missed "lyxtoaletter"... it means "luxury/luxurious toilets")

I actually vaguely remembered seeing it myself on TV (I'm from Norway), and especially that final scene.
